# Why is tableview hiding underneath search bar?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

So I have `UISearchController` where the search bar sits perfectly on top of the `UITableView` which is exactly how I want it. However, when I do a search and then click on a cell it goes to another view controller. But when I dismiss that View Controller and come back to the search view controller, the top of the tableview hides underneath the search bar and have no idea why. Help would be very much appreciated! Thanks in advance

Code that I'm currently using for a `UISearchController`

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

  searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        definesPresentationContext = true
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
 navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
 searchTableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

    }
```

Comment: What does the constraints look like in your storyBoard ?

Comment: I have the tableview leading trailing, top and bottom spacing all 0 to the superview

Comment: @j.iese are you presenting a new controller ? if so then are you dismissing UISearchbarController before presenting new controller ?

Comment: no I'm pushing to a new view controller @MuhammadWaqasBhati

Comment: Are you showing navigationbar of navigationController for both ViewControllers ?

Comment: yes I am @MuhammadWaqasBhati

Comment: You have to add this line in viewwillappear method. ....         tableVw.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: tableVw.tableHeaderView?.frame.size.height ?? 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

Comment: ok i tried it but it still didn't work @MuhammadWaqasBhati

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190624/discussion-between-muhammad-waqas-bhati-and-j-iese).